# Limit concurrent requests with Spray

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm using spray-routing to build a simple HTTP server.  This server calls out to a number of services that take a while to respond (seconds).  We would like to reject requests when the number of concurrent requests becomes to large.  Otherwise a large number of concurrent requests bogs down the system to nobody's advantage.

There are a number of layers where this might be solved.  I'm not sure how to do any of them precisely, or which is the best one.

1. I could supply an execution context for spray-routing that has a bounded queue and a rejection policy.
2. I could limit the mailbox size of my spray http server since it is also an actor.
3. I could configure a setting in `application.conf` that addresses this directly for spray.

What is a simple an effective way of implementing such a policy?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what solution would be the best for your case (I would go for creating my own execution context) but I believe that maybe you should rethink how you want to process your requests.

What do you do with your request? Do you try to handle them in Spray directly? With some help from Futures?

I would suggest creating additional actors, passing the request context to them and then deciding what to do. If you want to process it or maybe you should put it down immediately. This will give you much flexibility in future. You can attach additional servers with now support for clustering in Akka without changing the spray part adding more processing power easily.

I know this doesn't answer your question but I think akka was designed to handle this kind of problems differently and cutting on mailboxes or anything else is not the right choice.